# How to select datagrid's specific row using ViewModel for given row number say: make row no 2 selected in datagrid?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I am using MVVM light with silverlight 4. I am using EventToCommand to get selected rows from the datagrid. However i am not able to do it in reverse way i.e. from some defined value say 2 in view model how can I ask to place selection to row no 2 in the datagrid on view?'

My scenario I am using it for inserting new data in database. From ViewModel i am able to generate the new row in datagrid by adding one more item in ObservableCollection. Now I want to view to select that defined new row. How could I do that.

My logic is:
1. since we can have total number of data record we know which one is that last row.
2. By using the Last row's number I want to create some event that will tell datagrid to select that row.

I am working on this for few days and not getting any idea how it works using MVVM light.

Answer (score 0):

Am not using MVVM Light, but if I was to act upon a selection in a row, I would do it this way, provided you have a control that is binded:

```
private void simpleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as SimplePocoObject;
    if (cell != null) _context.RunReport(cell.ID, cell.ServerName);
    myDomainDataSource.Load(); // refresh grid
}
```